# Adding a function directly to "menuBar" buttons without creating a sub-menu or dropdown

Tags: python, pyqt5, menubar

I want to make menu in Python PyQt5 with a function directly linked to it and not with a the sub-menu or dropdown it creates. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
def create_menu(self):
    self.menu = self.menuBar()
    self.this = self.menu.addMenu('This')
    self.that = self.menu.addMenu('That')
    self.menu.show()
    
    self.this.addAction("I want to make it without this", self.there)
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `self.menu.addAction()`?

Comment: Note that there's no need in calling `self.menu.show()`, as the menubar is automatically displayed as soon as it's created (`menuBar()` also creates a new menubar if it doesn't exist yet). Obviously, I'm assuming `self` refers to a QMainWindow instance.